# Issue with creating a react app from vite

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, vite

I tried to create a react app using this command

`npm create vite@latest filemanager`

and then when i tried to run

`npm run`

i get this error

```
> filemanager@0.0.0 dev
> vite

sh: 1: vite: not found
```

I tried using `npm install` after deleting `node_modules` dir and `package-lock.json`

Still issue is the same.

I even tried to uninstall and reinstall node

still that doesn't change anything

I am kinda newbie with these js stuffs i am not sure of the terms or most of the process. Can someone help me out.

I am using `ubuntu 22`

and `node version 20.5`

I expect this to start the react app successfully.

My assumption is that npm appears to not be able to detect runnable programs in node_modules

Not sure i know how to fix it

Comment: After you create the new project are you changing directory _to_ that folder? Once you're in that folder are you running `npm install`? And you should probably then use `npm run dev` to ensure you're running the correct script.

Comment: Can you add the error from `vite` to the question? Its missing now.

Comment: @Andy yeh i switched to that folder

Comment: @RobinThomas thanks completely forgot to send full traceback

Comment: Run `npm i -g vite` first, and then do `npm create vite@latest filemanager`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `vite` first. Hence first run:

```
npm i -g vite
```

Then create your vite app by:

```
npm create vite@latest filemanager
```